# Doubt about the proxy in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: networking, command-line, proxy

ENG: I want to block the ability to change proxy settings from the graphical environment, meaning that the option to switch the proxy from 'Automatic' to 'None' cannot be modified from the graphical interface. Does anyone know how I can do this?